# Not able to getting highcharts legend label in order

Tags: ionic-framework, highcharts

i'm trying to show highchart legend in order like this

[image]

but im getting like this

[image]

please help me how to show in order like in first image

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you want is the columns lined up.  That just requires `legend.alignColumns = true`.

```
legend: {
    alignColumns: true,
    width: 500,
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/1fu20j4g/7/

Highcharts has a great API reference.  Here's everything you can do to a legend: [Highcharts Legend API Reference](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Barbara. But it did't work for me. its still showing unaligned columns

Comment: legend: { enabled: true, alignColumns: true,  width: 500,  layout: 'horizontal',padding: 5, itemMarginTop: 2, itemMarginBottom: 5,   x: 12,
      verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 25,
                floating: true, 

                shadow: false, 
               symbolRadius: 0,
               symbolHeight: 10,
                align: 'left',},  this is my complete legend

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9nsamwko/   Updated with your settings.  This works for me.  Can you make a fiddle that shows your problem?

Comment: thank you so much. i updated jsfiddle with my settings its working fine in jsfiddle but not working in chrome.

Comment: will any other components of chart  effects legend?

Comment: Are you using the same version of Highcharts?  Do you have any other js libraries?  Do you have CSS that could be impacting?  There are so many possibilities.  You have a working example, try adding your code to it until it breaks.  If you can share a broken example, we can help you fix it.